# incomplete response received from application nodejs

Tags: node.js, nginx

I'm using nodejs on nginx server. Sometimes the node app is crashing and returning 'incomplete response received from application'. What is causing this problem?

```
const Express = require('express');
const BodyParser = require('body-parser');
const Request = require('request');
const Conf = require('./conf');
const {db} = require('./lib/database');
const app = Express();

app.use(BodyParser.json());
app.use(BodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
    if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
        return res.sendStatus(200);
    }
    next();
});

app.post('/getProperty', (req, res) => {
    const sql = "SELECT ('['||(st_asgeojson(geom)::json)||']')::json FROM spt.spt  where id=" + req.body.id;
    db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        if (err) res.status(err.code).json({code: err.code, message: err.message}).end();
        (result.rows.length == 0) ? res.send([]) : res.send(result.rows[0].json);
    })
});

app.post('/getAnalysis', (req, res) => {
    const sql = "select value from test.test where id=" + req.body.id + " order by value asc";
    db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        if (err) result.status(err.code).json({code: err.code, message: err.message}).end();
        res.send(result.rows);
    })
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: It might been caused by not setting up the credentials for production properly, please check for `secret_token` and `secret_key_base`

Comment: How can I check?

Comment: look at this tutorial might be helpful [link](https://www.sitepoint.com/configuring-nginx-ssl-node-js/)

Comment: There is no secret_token or secret_key_base on documentation. How can I find secret key or secret_key_base?

Comment: please look at the configuration file of nginx make sure the ports your app is listening to is the same as on nginx config file follow this [link](https://medium.com/@utkarsh_verma/configure-nginx-as-a-web-server-and-reverse-proxy-for-nodejs-application-on-aws-ubuntu-16-04-server-872922e21d38) for reference

Answer (score 0):

If an error occurs, your code tries sending a response twice. You need to exit the function after sending the error response to the client, so either use `return` in your `if` or add an `else` below for the success response.
Sending multiple responses will dicsonnect the socket in express.

Comment: Your .end() in the error handler is redundant as well. .send() already calls .end().

Answer (score 0):

If we want to know this error in console.log

**.htaccess**

```
...

Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
IndexIgnore *
DirectoryIndex
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
# Simple URL redirect:
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:3000/$1 [P]
</IfModule>
```